# present dimension array in C programming

Tags: c, string

I am doing a assignment which is we have to push any string with combine form of [ ] and , then present string to the multiple dimension array.

example the input string is: `[qw,good,hello,hey,[we,need,to,eat],pretty,blue]`
then

if we enter the command : `array` we ll get the output: `[qw,good,hello,hey,[we,need,to,eat],pretty,blue]`.

If we enter the command array[3] we ll get the output: `hey`.

If we enter a command : array[4] we ll get the output `[we,need,to,eat]`.

If we enter a command array[4][2] we ll get the output is `to`

My idea is using the token to remove the special character but the trouble is the comma are both in multiple dimension array and outter the demension array.And one more problem is we dont know the input string , so it can be two dimensions array or 3D or 4D .Thank you

Comment: You'll probably have to scan the string one character at a time and take care of the special caharcetrs: an open bracket opens a sublist, a comma ends the current item and a closed bracked ends the current item closes a sublist. Everything else is data. You must keep a list of parent items, so you can go back when you find a closed bracket.

Comment: but scanning the comma, it can not tell anything about the string and size of array, I can use stack to scan the bracket but not sure  which one is inner in other.

Comment: Do you need to represent the array as data structure so that you parse the string only once and can answer many queries? Or do you parse and query at the same time, so that you can keep track of the indices while parsing? Anyway, you have a current level that is determined by the number of opening and closing brackets. A comma increases the index of the current level.

Comment: this can not be expressed as a simple array if the [data] and [[data]] are different. It does not allow you to simply define the array even if the level of nesting is 3 or more(no fixed limit). I think the structure, such as a list than array is suitable.

Comment: @hellocomputer so what code have you to show?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot simply parse and read `[qw,good,hello,hey,[we,need,to,eat],pretty,blue]` into a multidimensional array and access the elements in the manner you propose, because you are mixing storing `an array of character arrays` with `an array of an array of character arrays` (for sub strings `[we,need,to,eat]`). They have different pointers and cannot simply be added to a generic `array`. (yes you could set up some inane array of `void pointers` and some elaborate test mechanism to attempt to gracefully handle figuring out what was what (`tagged union` maybe), but that seems completely beyond what you are asking.

A much cleaner solution to meet your requirements would be an `array of structs` where the structure keeps track of its `array indexes` and whether it is a `sub-array`. That, fortunately is the trivial part of the question.

The non-trivial part of the question is parsing the input string and taking appropriate action based on the characters read. This isn't difficult, just tedious, and requires working from the beginning to end, essentially character-by-character.

At first blush it may appear a trivial `strtok` with delimiters of `"[,]"` may be a simple approach, but determining whether to assign an entry to the `main array`, or `sub-array`, takes knowing which of the terminating characters were encountered. This basically drops you back to a `brute-force, character-by-character` read.

After parsing and filling your array of structs, you will have to come up with an output routine that takes `1 (or 2) indexes`, searches your array of structs, and outputs the matching member if the indexes match.

Again, none of this is difficult, but you have the same type of `index accounting` to do. Below is one approach to filling your requirements. It is not filled with `error checking` the memory allocated to the `array of structs` still must be freed, and you need to check `MAXS` and reallocate as needed. Take a look, I think this will get you started:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXS 128

typedef struct {
    char *str;
    int subs;
    int maj;
    int min;
} sarray;

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input. Usage:  %s <delimited string> [,[,],]\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    char *input = strdup (argv[1]);
    char *sp = input;
    sarray **array = NULL;
    char *p = NULL;
    char sc = 0;
    int idx = 0;
    int sidx = 0;
    int pcnt = 0;
    char start_array = 0;

    if (*sp++ != '[') {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid sp, no opening '['. Usage:  %s <delimited string> [,[,],]\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("\nCreating array from input: %s\n\n", input);

    array = calloc (MAXS, sizeof (*array));
    if (!array) {
        printf ("\n  calloc failed\n\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while (*sp)
    {
        p = sp;                                     /* assign pointer equal start pointer (sp)  */
        array[pcnt] = malloc (sizeof (array));      /* allocate storage for new element         */

        while (*p != 0 && *p != '[' && *p != ',' && *p != ']') p++;     /* scan for delimiter   */


        /* test for double character (meaning beginning or end of sub-array */
        if (*(p+1) != 0)
            if (*(p+1) == '[' || *(p+1) == ',' || *(p+1) == ']') { *p=0; p++; }

        sc = *p;                                    /* save the current character (to restore)  */
        *p = 0;                                     /* set the ending delimiter to NULL         */

        array[pcnt]->str = strdup (sp);             /* allocate str and copy sp                 */
        array[pcnt]->subs = (start_array) ? 1 : 0;  /* set flag indicating it is a sub array    */
        array[pcnt]->maj = idx;                     /* assign major index for array             */
        array[pcnt]->min = sidx;                    /* assign minor index for array             */

        if (start_array) sidx++;                    /* increment major or minor per start_array */
        else idx++;

        pcnt++;                                     /* increment pointer index                  */
        *p = sc;                                    /* restor the saved character               */

        if (*p == '[') {                            /* if current is '[' begin sub array        */
            sidx = 0; 
            start_array = 1; 
        }
        if (*(p-1) == 0 && *p == ',') {             /* if current is ']' end sub array          */
            idx++; sidx = 0; 
            start_array = 0; 
        }

        sp = ++p;                                   /* set sp to next new character             */
    }

    if (input) free (input);                        /* free memory allocated to input           */

    /* output indexed array */
    idx = 0;
    while (array[idx])
    {
        if (array[idx]->subs)
            printf ("  array[%d][%d] : %s\n", array[idx]->maj, array[idx]->min, array[idx]->str);
        else
            printf ("  array[%d]    : %s\n", array[idx]->maj, array[idx]->str);

        idx++;
    }

    /* prompt for input of index(s) and output matching element */
    int  maj = 0;
    int  min = 0;
    int  printed = 0;
    idx = 0;

    printf ("\nEnter index to retrieve element (index [sub-index]): ");
    scanf ("%m[^\n]%*c", &input);

    p = input;
    while (*p++) idx++;
    if (idx > 1) {
        maj = input[0] - '0';
        min = input[idx-1] - '0';
    }
    else if (idx == 1) {
        maj = input[0] - '0';
        min = 0;    
    }
    else {
        printf ("\nerror: invalid index input, format X [Y]\n\n");
        return 1;
    }

    idx = 0;

    if (min > 0) {

        while (array[idx])
        {
            if (array[idx]->maj == maj && array[idx]->min == min) {
                printf ("\n  array[%d][%d] : %s\n\n", array[idx]->maj, array[idx]->min, array[idx]->str);
                printed = 1;
                break;
            }

            idx++;
        }
    }
    else {

        while (array[idx])
        {
            if (array[idx]->maj == maj) {
                if (array[idx]->subs == 1 && array[idx]->min == 0j) {
                    printf ("\n  array[%d]    :", idx);
                    while (array[idx]->subs == 1) {
                        printf (" %s", array[idx]->str);
                        idx++;
                    }
                    printf ("\n\n");
                }
                else {
                    printf ("\n  array[%d]    : %s\n\n", array[idx]->maj, array[idx]->str);
                }
                printed = 1;
                break;
            }

            idx++;
        }
    }

    if (!printed)
        printf ("\nerror: index not found.\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/strrdmulti [qw,good,hello,hey,[we,need,to,eat],pretty,blue]

Creating array from input: [qw,good,hello,hey,[we,need,to,eat],pretty,blue]

  array[0]    : qw
  array[1]    : good
  array[2]    : hello
  array[3]    : hey
  array[4][0] : we
  array[4][1] : need
  array[4][2] : to
  array[4][3] : eat
  array[5]    : pretty
  array[6]    : blue

Enter index to retrieve element (index [sub-index]): 2

  array[2]    : hello

$ ./bin/strrdmulti [qw,good,hello,hey,[we,need,to,eat],pretty,blue]

Creating array from input: [qw,good,hello,hey,[we,need,to,eat],pretty,blue]

  {array omitted}

Enter index to retrieve element (index [sub-index]): 4

  array[4]    : we need to eat

$ ./bin/strrdmulti [qw,good,hello,hey,[we,need,to,eat],pretty,blue]

Creating array from input: [qw,good,hello,hey,[we,need,to,eat],pretty,blue]

  {array omitted}

Enter index to retrieve element (index [sub-index]): 4 2

  array[4][2] : to

$ ./bin/strrdmulti [qw,good,hello,hey,[we,need,to,eat],pretty,blue]

Creating array from input: [qw,good,hello,hey,[we,need,to,eat],pretty,blue]

  {array omitted}

Enter index to retrieve element (index [sub-index]): 4 4

error: index not found.
```

Comment: this works perfect, but I dont understand the format of input  scanf ("%m[^\n]%*c", &input) is.